# Converting POJO to 'record" as a result of migrating from Java 8 to 17 causes error Firestore error

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, java-17

Following migration from Java 8 to 17, I thought of converting POJO models to records for better readability. However, when making the call to `DocumentSnapshot.toObject(MyRecord.class)` in this block of code

```
DocumentSnapshot document = future.get();
if (document.exists()) {
    MyRecord myRecord = document.toObject(MyRecord.class);

    if (myRecord != null) {
        fetchData(myRecord);
    }

    return myRecord;
}
```

, a RuntimeException is thrown: `java.lang.RuntimeException: No properties to serialize found on class com.comp.api.firestorerest.model.myrecord.MyRecord`.

I did some research to learn more about records and Firestore, as I'm trying to see if this can actually be accomplished by combining records with the Firestore library, but I haven't found much. Is there a way to use records this way? Otherwise, I'll just revert to POJO.

`DocumentSnapshot` comes from the `google-cloud-firestore` [library](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.cloud/google-cloud-firestore/3.14.0).

Here's a sample of `MyRecord`

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public record MyRecord(String aString1,
                            String aString2,
                            String aString3,
                            String aString4,
                            String aString5,
                            String aString6,
                            int anInt,
                            Map<String, List<String>> services) {
}
```

Comment: What is `DocumentSnapshot`? If this comes from an external framework not of your own creation, name the framework and provide a link.

Comment: Would you like to show us `MyRecord`?  We should have enough information in the question to be able to duplicate the behavior you observe on our own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't make any difference if you're using a regular Java class or a record. You're getting the following error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: No properties to serialize found on class com.comp.api.firestorerest.model.myrecord.MyRecord

Because the names of the fields inside the record class are different from the ones that exist in the database. To make things clear, I'll show you an example. Let's assume we have a collection of documents that contain a single field called `name` and a record class that looks like this:

```
public record MyRecord(
        String name
) {}
```

So when you try to map a Firestore document into an object of type `MyRecord` using the following line of code:

```
MyRecord myRecord = document.toObject(MyRecord.class);
```

You will indeed get the above error, and that's because in order to access the `name` field inside the record class, you'll have to call `name()`, which is actually the getter of the field. In order to deserialize such an object, the getter should be named `getName()` and not only `name()`, hence the error.

Besides that, in order to create a new instance of the record class, Firestore SDK needs the no-argument constructor. Which in your `MyRecord` class is **not** present. That's because when you create a constructor with an argument, the no-argument constructor goes away. So to be able to deserialize such objects, it's mandatory to define the no-argument constructor. Besides that, you should also use an annotation so you can indicate the name of the field in class to exactly match the one in the database. So the above record class should be rewritten like this:

```
public record MyRecord(
        @PropertyName("name")
        String getName
) {
    public MyRecord() {
        this("");
    }
}
```

Now you'll be able to map a document into an object of a record class. To get the name, you can use the following line of code:

```
String name = document.toObject(MyRecord.class).getName();
```

Comment: Thanks for you explanation. This clears things up. When implementing it this way though, I still get the error: `java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Can not set final java.lang.String field com.comp.api.firestorerest.model.myrecord.MyRecord.getName to java.lang.String`. I suspect that it's trying to use a setter, but records don't have setters and al the fields are declared as `final`. Hence why the error.

Comment: All fields that exist inside the constructor of a record class, are by default **final**. This means that you cannot change the value of a final variable, hence that error. Even if these record classes in Java are fancy, I still use POJO classes, or in Kotlin, data classes.

Comment: Yeah for my use case, it's just better to revert to POJO. Records aren't resolving anything for me in my use case. I'll just use lombok to generate everything. Thanks!